# Mysql and PHP LIKE query generates no results on page but returns result in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im using a multiple LiKE queries on a table in mysql, The query is being generated from another table and then sent to Mysql. The actual query when run generates results but when i run it on the page it returns nothing?? Secondly there must be a simpler way to run the same query using less LIKE command maybe

```
mysql_query("SELECT FROM fm_sources WHERE title,excerpt LIKE (list of items to query against)")
```

this is the code that im using to build the query

```
function parse_club_search($club)
{
    $club="'%".$club."%'";
    $club=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fm_clubs WHERE name LIKE $club");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($club))
{
    $search_string=$row['search'];
    $search_staff=$row['staff'];
    $search_players=$row['players'];
}

$search_string=explode(",",$search_string);
$search_staff=explode(",",$search_staff);
$search_players=explode(",",$search_players);

$full_string=array_merge($search_staff,$search_players,$search_string);
array_pop($full_string);
$full_string_legnth=count($full_string);

$sql_query_holder="";

$array_track=0;

foreach($full_string as $tag)
{

   if($array_track!=($full_string_legnth-1))
   {
        echo $tag."<br/>";
        $sql_query_holder=$sql_query_holder." excerpt LIKE '%".$tag."%' OR title LIKE '%".$tag."%' OR";
        $array_track++;
    }
    else
    {
        $sql_query_holder=$sql_query_holder." excerpt LIKE '%".$tag."%' OR title LIKE '%".$tag."%'";
        $array_track++;
    }
}

echo $sql_query_holder."<br/><br/>";

$sql_query_holder="\"".$sql_query_holder."\"";
$search=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fm_sources WHERE $sql_query_holder ORDER BY tweet_count DESC");
```

and this is the echoed output of the query and then when run no results.

> excerpt LIKE '%Roy Hodgson%' OR title
>   LIKE '%Roy Hodgson%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Sammy Lee%' OR title LIKE '%Sammy
>   Lee%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Kenny
>   Dalglish%' OR title LIKE '%Kenny
>   Dalglish%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Brad
>   Jones%' OR title LIKE '%Brad Jones%'
>   OR excerpt LIKE '%Glen Johnson%' OR
>   title LIKE '%Glen Johnson%' OR excerpt
>   LIKE '%Paul Konchesky%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Paul Konchesky%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Raul Meireles%' OR title LIKE '%Raul
>   Meireles%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Daniel
>   Agger%' OR title LIKE '%Daniel Agger%'
>   OR excerpt LIKE '%Fabio Aurelio%' OR
>   title LIKE '%Fabio Aurelio%' OR
>   excerpt LIKE '%Steven Gerrard%' OR
>   title LIKE '%Steven Gerrard%' OR
>   excerpt LIKE '%Fernando Torres%' OR
>   title LIKE '%Fernando Torres%' OR
>   excerpt LIKE '%Joe Cole%' OR title
>   LIKE '%Joe Cole%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Daniel Pacheco%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Daniel Pacheco%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Milan Jovanovic%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Milan Jovanovic%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Sotirios Kyrgiakos%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Sotirios Kyrgiakos%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Maxi Rodriguez%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Maxi Rodriguez%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Dirk Kuyt%' OR title LIKE '%Dirk
>   Kuyt%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Ryan Babel%'
>   OR title LIKE '%Ryan Babel%' OR
>   excerpt LIKE '%Lucas%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Lucas%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Danny
>   Wilson%' OR title LIKE '%Danny
>   Wilson%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Jamie
>   Carragher%' OR title LIKE '%Jamie
>   Carragher%' OR excerpt LIKE '%David
>   NGog%' OR title LIKE '%David NGog%' OR
>   excerpt LIKE '%Pepe Reina%' OR title
>   LIKE '%Pepe Reina%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Jay Spearing%' OR title LIKE '%Jay
>   Spearing%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Christian
>   Poulsen%' OR title LIKE '%Christian
>   Poulsen%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Charles
>   Itandje%' OR title LIKE '%Charles
>   Itandje%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Stephen
>   Darby%' OR title LIKE '%Stephen
>   Darby%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Jonjo
>   Shelvey%' OR title LIKE '%Jonjo
>   Shelvey%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Martin
>   Kelly%' OR title LIKE '%Martin Kelly%'
>   OR excerpt LIKE '%Steven Irwin%' OR
>   title LIKE '%Steven Irwin%' OR excerpt
>   LIKE '%Martin Skrtel%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Martin Skrtel%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Nathan Eccleston%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Nathan Eccleston%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Daniel Ayala%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Daniel Ayala%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Martin Hansen%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Martin Hansen%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Peter Gulacsi%' OR title LIKE
>   '%Peter Gulacsi%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%Dean Bouzanis%' OR title LIKE '%Dean
>   Bouzanis%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Victor
>   Palsson%' OR title LIKE '%Victor
>   Palsson%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Tom Ince%'
>   OR title LIKE '%Tom Ince%' OR excerpt
>   LIKE '%David Amoo%' OR title LIKE
>   '%David Amoo%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Andre
>   Wisdom%' OR title LIKE '%Andre
>   Wisdom%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Gerardo
>   Bruna%' OR title LIKE '%Gerardo
>   Bruna%' OR excerpt LIKE '%Jack
>   Robinson%' OR title LIKE '%Jack
>   Robinson%' OR excerpt LIKE
>   '%liverpool%' OR title LIKE
>   '%liverpool%' OR excerpt LIKE '%lfc%'
>   OR title LIKE '%lfc%'

Comment: And holy cow, that can't be an efficient query. It looks like you could benefit greatly from normalization.

Comment: sorry about that just read your blog post,i didnt realise i had to accept and answer and i couldnt vote for it with low rep. I'll go back and accept the answers on my previous questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$sql_query_holder="\"".$sql_query_holder."\"";
```

Your script doesn't output the whole query, just part of it, which it then modifies.  No wonder you couldn't see what was wrong.

The query it's running is actually:

```
SELECT * FROM fm_sources WHERE "excerpt LIKE '%Roy Hodgson%' OR title LIKE '%Roy Hodgson%' <etc etc> " ORDER BY tweet_count DESC
```

You don't need those extra inverted commas